# Application Insights - Custom Performance Counter

Tags: azure-application-insights

I can instantiate a new performance counter object, but how can i "track" it? there's "TrackTrace", "TrackException", and etc, but theres no "TrackPerformanceCounter"... Any work around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no workaround... there are some open issues on the GITHUB project to increase/configure the recurrence of data capture but nothing concrete as of sep/2017

Answer (score 1):

if you're using a real performance counter, then you'd configure your applicationinsights.config to collect that performance counter, and it just would happen normally. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-performance-counters)

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
  <Counters>
    <Add PerformanceCounter="\Objects\Processes"/>
    <Add PerformanceCounter="\Sales(photo)\# Items Sold" ReportAs="Photo sales"/>
  </Counters>
</Add>
```

if you're not using real performance counters and simply want to track the value of a number, you'd use either `TrackMetric(nameOfThing, valueOfThing)` directly, or you can track the value of that metric at any time by passing it in the `metrics` param in any of the `TrackEvent( nameOfEvent, properties, metrics)` calls.

Comment: oh, and, if i use the track metric, will it appear for the query `performanceCounters` or only 'customMetric'?

Comment: if you use a custom metrics, it will go to `customMetrics` table.  you could do `union customMetrics, performanceCounters` to do queries against both.  checking on how often the sdk collects perfcounters, considering a ton of stuff is built on top of perfcounters, i'm surprised it isn't frequent enough for you.

Comment: sdk collects perf counters once a minute, see https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/142  for the github info about it, and upvote https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/8891389-support-for-changing-custom-performance-counter-sa if you need it configurable